# Dynamicly created Variable Scope in a for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, return-value, scope

I'm trying to create a function that I can't share it's full contents, however I'll try to explain the part that isn't working as intended.

This block is supposed to iterate through an array and do some math to it's values, the values obtained within one iteration will need to be used in the next.

Code:

```
$input = 100000; //EDIT2 start
$arr = array();

for($i=1; $i<$input; $i) {
    $i *= 36;
    $arr[] = $i;
}
array_pop($arr); //EDIT2 end
$max = max(array_keys($arr));

for ($i=$max; $i>=0; $i--){
    if ($i == $max) {
        ${'result'.$i} = (int) ($input / $arr[$i]);
        ${'step'.$i} = $input - (${'result'.$i} * $arr[$i]);
        echo $i.'= '.${'result'.$i}.'<br>';
        echo $i.'= '.${'step'.$i}.'<br>';
    }
    elseif ($i == 0) {
        //outputs $step0
    }
    else {
        ${'result'.$i} = (int) (${'step'.$i+1} / $arr[$i]);
        ${'step'.$i} = ${'step'.$i+1} - (${'result'.$i} * $arr[$i]);
        echo $i.'= '.${'result'.$i}.'<br>';
        echo $i.'= '.${'step'.$i}.'<br>';
    }
}
```

This outputs `$i=` properly so I'm sure it runs through the whole thing as intended, but only outputs the first iteration's `result` and `step` correctly. I'm assuming it has to do with the variable scope, however there might be something wrong in the variable's name creation `{'result'.$i}` although that would prevent the first iteration from returning the right values.

As a continuation question, I would then like to replace the `echo`'s with return value pairs... would you suggest committing the values to an array within each iteration, or something like `return ${'result'.$i}, ${'step'.$i};` (does the last syntax work like that?)

Hope it's an easy solution... took me quite a while to shorten the problem down to this little thing.

**EDIT:---------**

```
//if ($i == $max)
$result2 = (int) ( $input / $arr[2]);    //to be returned, should be = 2
$step2 = $input - ($result2 * $arr[2]);  //should be = 6688

//else
$result1 = (int) ( $step2 / $arr[1]);    //to be returned, should be = 5
$step1 = $step2 - ($result1 * $arr[1]);  //should be = 208

//elseif ($i == 0)
$result0 = (int) ( $step1 / $arr[0]);    //to be returned, should be = 5
$step0 = $step1 - ($result0 * $arr[0]);  //to be returned, should be = 28
```

This is what I need the loop to do, but adding to the center block, when $i is neither max index or 0. I started out by doing the math to figure out what pattern would be needed then tried to translate it into a loop, might have overcomplicated, I usually do xD This might help out with what's intended.

**EDIT2:---------**

Added the beginning of the code. The main idea is converting `$input` into another smaller value (alphanumeric), given an array with 36 indexes. This code would generate the index values of that array, needed to convert the number. Some sort of custom made encryption. They key array for that encryption could be something like `$key[]=array(A,B,C,....,7,8,9);` depending on the indexes provided by the loop, the shortened version of the `$input` would be created. The values (2, 5, 5, 28) are the indexes of the `$key` array to build the short version of `$input`.

Comment: `global $var` does not declare a global variable, it retrieves an already declared variable from the global scope.

Comment: why are you using so many variables `${'result'.$i}`? isn't it much easier to use arrays? if you want to return the values it will be much easier with arrays.

Comment: Wow when I thought *"I'd like to see dollar signs this morning..."* this is not what I meant.  It's still difficult to follow friend.  How about posting the initial state of your input - the math (as pseudo) that you'd like to apply to each input and for completeness the expected output state/s.

Comment: @Emissary added more code... don't have anymore xD Hope it helps. If you make a php file with this code it'll output $i=1 properly, and ($i=2 and $i=3) = 0 where it should present different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected the code, it's working now. Thks for the pointers guys... gotta keep focused on thinking simple.

Code:

```
$input = 100000;
$arr = array();

for($i=1; $i<$input; $i) {
    $i *= 36;
    $arr[] = $i;
}

array_pop($arr);
$max = max(array_keys($arr));
$result = array();
$step = array();
$output = array();

for ($i=$max; $i>=0; $i--){
    if ($i == $max) {
        $result[$i] = (int) ($input / $arr[$i]);
        $step[$i] = $input - ($result[$i] * $arr[$i]);
        echo $i.'= '.$result[$i].'<br>';
        echo $i.'= '.$step[$i].'<br>';
        array_push($output, $result[$i]);
    }
    elseif ($i == 0) {
        $result[$i] = (int) ($step[$i+1] / $arr[$i]);
        $step[$i] = $step[$i+1] - ($result[$i] * $arr[$i]);
        echo $i.'= '.$result[$i].'<br>';
        echo $i.'= '.$step[$i].'<br>';
        array_push($output, $result[$i], $step[$i]);
    }
    else {
        $result[$i] = (int) ($step[$i+1] / $arr[$i]);
        $step[$i] = $step[$i+1] - ($result[$i] * $arr[$i]);
        echo $i.'= '.$result[$i].'<br>';
        echo $i.'= '.$step[$i].'<br>';
        array_push($output, $result[$i]);
    }
}
echo var_dump($output);
```

Echoes:

```
2= 2
2= 6688
1= 5    //was echoing "1= 0"
1= 208  //was echoing "1= 0"
0= 5    //was echoing "0= 0"
0= 28   //was echoing "0= 0"
array(4) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(5) [2]=> int(5) [3]=> int(28) }
```

This was the intended result

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly why you're trying to dynamically create variables, unless you plan to use them outside of the loop. I would say just use the variables $result and $step and overwrite them every iteration, or use arrays and use $i as the index. You're making this way more complex than it needs to be unless im oblivious to something you're trying to accomplish.

Also, No you cannot return pairs. You may return an array containing the data or you can pass by reference, hard to tell what you're returning to though. Maybe a more complete chunk of code would help.

Comment: Added some more code, it's basically breaking down the math to get the needed results into blocks that could then be put into a loop.  From what you said I'm thinking `$result[]`, `$step[]` and `$return[]` where I commit the values into the array without specifying the index, since `$i` goes backwards and use `$step[$max-$i]` to access the previous index... how does that sound? Over complicating again?

Comment: much better idea. No Need to create dynamic variables - that's what arrays are for! Still not seeing where you would return anything, but hope it works out for you!

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is you may have more than 1 variable and operation on more than one variable in a for loop.